# Where does CodeIgniter place newly created webpages?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am building a web server locally using CodeIgniter and am trying to add a new page to my website. However, after creating the Controller and View files for the page I cannot access the new page at (what I think is) the desired address.

This is on a Pi running PHP 5 and Apache 2 with CodeIgniter 2.2.6. I have been able to access other pages to work through just writing the Controller and view files, but I can not access this one.

### Controller page code (file name: Display_Live_State.php)

```
<?php

class Display_Live_State extends CI_Controller {

public function __construct()
{
    //Construct page
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->helper('url_helper');
}

public static function view()
{
    $this->load->view('Display_Live_State_view', $data);
}

}

?>
```

### View page code (file name: Display_Live_State_view.php)

```
<body>
    <div>This is a test</div>
</body>
```

I expect to find a page with the test sentence on it at path localhost/index.php/Display_Live_State/view as I have created other pages with similar filepaths (except for the name of the controller) and have been able to access them.

If someone could enlighten me as to where CodeIgniter 'puts' the website when created, or show me what I did wrong / where the page is if it exists, I would be very grateful. Thanks.

Comment: It doesn't put it anywhere. You do. https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide2/general/routing.html

Comment: Thank you for your comment ceejayoz, I was able to fix my problem and now know more about codeignitor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `Display_Live_State` to `Display_live_state` both in the class declaration e.g. `class Display_live_state` and in the filename `application/controllers/Display_live_state.php`.

Set your `base_url` if you haven't already to `http://localhost`.

You should be able to access your controller via the url: `localhost/index.php/Display_Live_State/view`

Comment: Thank you for your help Alex, your suggested solution fixed the problem.

Comment: Always follow uppercase first letter, lower case rest and you'll be fine!